# Dynatree - Open link in a new window many time

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

With dynatree I want to open the link selected by the user in a new window and to have the new window focused. I obtained this so:

```
            if (node.data.url) {
                window.open(node.data.url);
                return stop;
            };
```

where "stop" is undefined. Is there another way?
But there is more.
If I click again the same link 
(example Fraer Leasing)
nothing happens (and I want another window opened for that link).
How can i do?
Please, if possible, answer wih examples.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the [sample](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-iframe.html)

```
 onActivate: function(node) {
    if( node.data.href ){
      window.open(node.data.href, node.data.target);
    }
 }
```

The `onActivate` event is only triggered once, i.e. when the node was inactive before.
You could implement the `onClick` event instead.